# Works only one function in implemented file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file with two functions, one in plain javascript and one using jQuery. I want both to work on window load. But if I enable both, only the plain javascript function works. When I disabled the "highliter" function "slideSwitch" works ok. What is the problem? How can I fix this?

```
function slideSwitch() {        
    var active = $('#slideshow img.active'),
    next;

    if (active.length == 0){
        active = $('#slideshow img:last');
    };

    next = active.next().length ? active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');

    active.addClass('last-active');

    next.addClass('active')
        .css({opacity:0.0})
        .animate({opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {            
            active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
};


function startSlideShow() {
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
};


function highliter() {
    var current = document.location.pathname;
    var nav = document.getElementById('pages');
    var a_tags = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i <= a_tags.length; i++) {
        if (a_tags[i].getAttribute('href') === current) {
            a_tags[i].parentElement.className = 'highlited';
        }
    }
};


window.onload = function() {
    highliter();
    startSlideShow();
};
```

Comment: I would have to ask why you are not using JQuery for highliter too. There is no reason why JQ and JS should not work in the same file, so there is clearly something wrong with the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a javascript error occurring in highliter()? I see two possible issues:

1. Your for loop is checking <= length instead of < length, meaning you're exceeding the size of the array.
2. I could see there not being an element on the page with an id of 'pages', which would mean nav is null and the subsequent access on nav results in a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `parentElement`, it is `parentNode`.